# Suspend on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management

I'm a total newbie with Linux and I'd like to create an home NAS. I just installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a USB stick, moved tmp folders to RAM, installed LAMP, Webadmin and enabled the Firewall.

Since I'm the only user I'd like to be able to suspend the NAS after X minutes of idle to reduce power consumption. I know that a NAS is supposed to be on 24/7 but that's not my case.

How can i do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sspender https://github.com/mountassir/sspender

It allows you to suspend your machine based on pre-defined CPU/Disk usage, and makes sure the machine wakes up at certain times when you need it to be ON.